# Is it necessary to enable "atime" in /etc/fstab to get the correct last accessed time in java?

Tags: java, linux, lastaccesstime

I can get the last accessed time by using the below code.

```
public Date getLastAccessTime(String filePath) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(filePath);
    BasicFileAttributes basicFileAttributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(
        f.toPath(),
        BasicFileAttributeView.class).readAttributes();
    Date accessTime = new Date(basicFileAttributes.lastAccessTime().toMillis());
    return accessTime;
}
```

But in my linux system, it's configured as "relatime" in /etc/fstab.

Is it necessary to enable "atime" in /etc/fstab to get exact Last Accessed Time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it necessary to enable "atime" in /etc/fstab to get exact Last Accessed Time?

Short answer: Yes

On Linux the JDK uses the `sys_stat64()` syscall to retrieve information about file. If the kernel does not update the `st_atime` field when the file is accessed then Java can't have this information.

The default behavior of the Linux kernel regarding the st_atime updating policy has been changed by Linux 2.6.30. `relatime` is now the default dehavior. It means that `st_atime` is updated only when `st_mtime` or `st_ctime` is updated but not when the file is accessed. If you want the *old* behavior you can use `strictatime`. See the mount man page for more information (search for `atime`, `noatime`, `relatime`, `strictatime`).